# Using onBlur after upgrade to React 17

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events, onblur

I have a div as below.

```
<div
 id={'editor1'}
 tabIndex={-1} 
 onBlur={this._blurHandler}
>
```

I am noticing that after upgrading to React version 17.0.1 (from 16.13.1), the `this._blurHandler` is not getting invoked.

I did read up on the breaking changes - https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/08/10/react-v17-rc.html#other-breaking-changes and see that "onBlur events have switched to using the native focusin and focusout" instead of focus.

While I am on react 17, is there a way I can get back the original behavior that would invoke `this._blurHandler` upon blur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between `onBlur` and `focusout` (native events not React) is that `focusout` does propegate while `onBlur` doesn't. So try adding `e.stopPropegation()` to your React `onBlur` / `onFocus` Events.

Comment: just adding e.stopPropegation() might not be enough. But the problem most likely stems from Propegation - so that's the direction I would be looking for a solution at

Comment: Thanks for the response! Trying to understand - after the switch to 17, the `_blurHandler` does not get called whereas, previously, it was getting called. Are you suggesting adding e.stopPropagation() inside the `_blurHandler`? I would think the solution has to do with getting  `_blurHandler` to be invoked like before?
@Lord-JulianXLII

Comment: @LearnToImprove the problem is: I suspect the problem having to to with the fact, that now blur/focus will bubble - so you'd have to look at the parent/children elements to understand the problem. - are you by any chance clicking on a child of your div (in that case the focusin would bubble back to the div so no Blur/focusout would occur)

Comment: that makes sense. Let me try a bit and come back.